# PHP: Running function + move_uploaded_file won't do?

Tags: php

In my upload photo script, at the processing part, when it moves the upload file to the uploaded_files:

```
@move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'], $uploadFilename)
    or error('receiving directory insuffiecient permission', $uploadForm);
```

Before this I added a function:

```
makeThumbnail($_FILES[$fieldname]['type'], $_FILES[$fieldname]['name'], $_FILES[$fieldname]['size'], $_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'], 100);
```

that makes it a thumbnail. I wish to have the original image *and* a thumbnail of it, but somehow it only works if I either remove the `makeThumbnail()` or `move_uploaded_file()`, and then I can't get both the image and the thumbnail...

I think it's because the tmp_name gets removed after one of these have been executed, so what do I do to keep it for the both?

My thumb function:

```
function makeThumbnail($type, $name, $size, $tmp_name, $thumbSize) {
    $path_thumbs = "uploaded_files/";       
    $img_thumb_width = $thumbSize; // 
    $extlimit = "yes"; //Limit allowed extensions? (no for all extensions allowed)

    //List of allowed extensions if extlimit = yes
    $limitedext = array(".gif",".jpg",".png",".jpeg",".bmp");

    //the image -> variables
    $file_type = $type;
    $file_name = $name;
    $file_size = $size; 
    $file_tmp = $tmp_name;

    //check if you have selected a file.
    if(!is_uploaded_file($file_tmp)){
        echo "Error: Please select a file to upload!. <br>--<a href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]\">back</a>";
        exit(); //exit the script and don't process the rest of it!
    }

    //check the file's extension
    $ext = strrchr($file_name,'.');
    $ext = strtolower($ext);

    //uh-oh! the file extension is not allowed!
    if (($extlimit == "yes") && (!in_array($ext,$limitedext))) {
        echo "Wrong file extension.  <br>--<a href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]\">back</a>";
        exit();
    }

    //so, whats the file's extension?
    $getExt = explode ('.', $file_name);
    $file_ext = $getExt[count($getExt)-1];

    //create a random file name
    $rand_name = md5(time());
    $rand_name= rand(0,999999999);

    //the new width variable
    $ThumbWidth = $img_thumb_width;

    /////////////////////////////////
    // CREATE THE THUMBNAIL //
    ////////////////////////////////

    //keep image type
    if($file_size){
        if($file_type == "image/pjpeg" || $file_type == "image/jpeg"){
            $new_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($file_tmp);
        }elseif($file_type == "image/x-png" || $file_type == "image/png"){
            $new_img = imagecreatefrompng($file_tmp);
        }elseif($file_type == "image/gif"){
            $new_img = imagecreatefromgif($file_tmp);
        }

        //list the width and height and keep the height ratio.
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file_tmp);

        //calculate the image ratio
        $imgratio=$width/$height;

        if ($imgratio>1){
            $newwidth = $ThumbWidth;
            $newheight = $ThumbWidth/$imgratio;
        }else{
            $newheight = $ThumbWidth;
            $newwidth = $ThumbWidth*$imgratio;
        }

        //function for resize image.
        if (function_exists(imagecreatetruecolor)){
            $resized_img = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);
        }else{
            die("Error: Please make sure you have GD library ver 2+");
        }

        //the resizing is going on here!
        imagecopyresampled($resized_img, $new_img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

        //finally, save the image
        ImageJpeg ($resized_img,"$path_thumbs/$rand_name.$file_ext", 100);
        ImageDestroy ($resized_img);
        ImageDestroy ($new_img);
    }

    //ok copy the finished file to the thumbnail directory
    // move_uploaded_file ($file_tmp, "$path_big/$rand_name.$file_ext");

    exit();
}
```

Comment: What exactly is that `exit()` doing at the end of your `makeThumbnail()` function? Is this the exact function you're calling before doing the `move_uploaded_file()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you've defined the `makeThumbnail()` function take parameters passed by reference, there's no way anything inside that function could remove the original data in the $_FILES array.

However, if you are running the `move_uploaded_files()` before you build the thumbnail, then there's your problem. It literally moves the file from its temporary storage location, as specified in `$_FILES[...]['tmp_name']` to the destination filename. Then there'll be nothing left for your thumbnail generator to work on.

Make it generate the thumbnail first and things should work better.

As a security tip, don't trust the `['type']` parameter in the $_FILES array. That's set by the client, and can be forged. Best to determine what kind of image you've got with [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/getimagesize) or [`fileinfo()`](http://php.net/fileinfo), which work purely server-side.

followup:

Man that's some ugly code. Some problems:

1. You extract the file extension twice, but are using the filename as supplied by the user, which is insecure.
2. You check for the existence of the 'gd' library AFTER you've already used gd functions, so the check is absolutely useless.
3. You pass in various parts of the $_FILES array to the function, but then simply reassign the paramters to other variables, in at least one case twice
4. You generate a random file name, but it's only an up-to-9 digit number, and don't check for collisions, so at some point, you'll overwrite an older image with the new upload.
5. You don't return this random file name, so how will you be able to associate the randomly named thumbnail with the original image?
6. You're not checking if the upload completed properly. Checking the `['size']` parameter isn't enough. A partial upload will still have a `['size']` but the file will be truncated and corrupted.
7. You have a basic "allowed types" filter, but what if you turn it off and the user uploads a .pdf, or random garbage, or a .exe, or even an image type that GD doesn't support?

So, to fix this, change your function call to this:

```
makeThumbnail($_FILE[$fieldname], 100);
```

There's no reason to pass in all those parameters manually when they're already nicely grouped in an array for you. Now that we have all the available data passed in, we can start doing stuff:

```
function makeThumbnail($file, $thumbSize = 100) {
    if ($file['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        // something blew up
        // so handle error condition
        // 
        // error codes documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php
        die();
    }

    $path_thumbs = "uploaded_files/";
    $allowed_types = array('image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/bmp', 'image/png', 'image/gif');

    $imageinfo = getimagesize($file['tmp_name']); // get image info

    if ($imageinfo === FALSE) {
        die("Uhoh. Unable to read uploaded file");
    }

    if (!in_array($imageinfo['mime'], $allowed_types)) {
        die("Sorry, images of type {$imageinfo['mime']} not allowed");
    }

    $rand_name = rand(0, 999999999); // this isn't particularly well done, but ...

    // create thumbnail
    switch($imageinfo['mime']) {
        case 'image/jpeg':
        case 'image/jpg':
            $new_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($file['tmp_name']);
            $file_ext = '.jpg';
            break;
        case 'image/gif':
            $new_img = imagecreatefromgif($file['tmp_name']);
            $file_ext = '.gif';
            break;
        case 'image/png':
            $new_img = imagecreatefrompng($file['tmp_name');
            $file_ext = '.png';
            break;
        default:
            die("Uhoh. How did we get here? Unsupported image type"):
    }

    $imgratio = $imageinfo['height'] / $imageinfo['width'];
    if ($imgratio > 1) {
        $newwidth = $thumbSize;
        $newheight = $thumbSize / $imgratio;
    } else {
        $newheight = $thumbSize;
        $newwidth = $thumbSize * $imgratio;
    }

    $resized_img = imagecreatefromtruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
    imagecopyresampled($resized_img, $new_img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

    $thumb_name = $rand_name . $file_ext;
    $thumb_path = $path_thumbs . '/' . $rand_name;
    imagejpeg($resized_img, $thumb_path);

    imagedestroy($resized_img);
    imagedestroy($new_img);

    return($thumb_name);
}
```

This is, of course, untested, just going from your original code and off the top of my head, but it should get you started on road to something that works better.

Comment: I tried to generate the thumbnail ..before.. moving, but then it doesnt move it and only makes the thumbnail

Comment: Please check my updated question, maybe something in the makeThumbnail() function is preventing it from move_uploaded_files() ? (just a thought)

Comment: Thanks for making me think newer. I tried your code, but unfortunaly the first thing i got was syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting '&' or T_VARIABLE, on the function makeThumbnail($file.. line And i wonder why you have set , 100, at the function? Because when you call it there's already makeThumbnail($_FILE[$fieldname], 100);.

Comment: @Karem, that was probably just a typo (he did say it was untested). He probably either meant `function makeThumbnail($file, $thumbSize)` or `function makeThumbnail($file, $thumbSize = 100)`. With that last one 100 is the default thumbnail size, so you can call it as `makeThumbnail($_FILE[$fieldname])` if you want the thumbnails to be 100 pixels in size.

Comment: Ok did that, and then there was one other error, die("Uhoh. How did we get here? Unsupported image type"): should end with and ; 
Now i get none errors, and nothing uploaded at all. Neither the normal picture or the resized one. Any ideas why?

Comment: You have to do some basic debugging yourself. we can't guess at what the problem is. Did you check if the file's really uploaded? Put some echoes in various spots of the function to say which stage you've reached. Does the script die early? Is there anything in the server's log?

Comment: No image gets uploaded. Its only within the thumbnail function, as when i remove the line that calls after it, it uploads the normal sized image fine. Ok im trying to debugging, coming back for more in a little while

Comment: I highly doubt the presence or absence of a function would affect the upload, since the upload is completed BEFORE the script is ever fired up.

Comment: Ok i think i found it. it's dieing at the if ($file['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) thats why i didnt get anything .. before that if statement i tried echo $file["tmp_name"]; seems like $file doesnt have any values?

Comment: Fixed, when you calling function there was a missing S in $_FILES. I got new error on this line:     if ($imgratio > 1) { , Division by zero ?

Comment: $imageinfo['height'] . " - ". $imageinfo['width']; are empty values, thats why i get that error above. And imageinfo is getimagesize();.. how should i solve this, what have went wrong?

Comment: Ok i did a new line:
 list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = $imageinfo;
and then changed the variable to   $imgratio = $height / $width;
Now that error goes away, and i think the last ones remaining it says Call to undefined function imagecreatefromtruecolor()  .even if i doublechecked and echo'd out the $newheight and $newwidth, they both got value but it says undefined, why?

Comment: changed imagecreatefromtruecolor() to imagecreatetruecolor() and that made the script work! Finally.. But it saves the thumb file without a extension like .jpg?

Comment: OK wasnt so hard to do, just changed added . $file_ext to the $thumb_path variable. That made it. Works perfectly now, answer accepted

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to create the thumbnail *after* moving the temp-file? Makes more sense to me than working in the temp-directory.

Comment: Then i would need to rewrite whole my function makeThumbnail()

Answer (score 0):

if you think temp variable is overwritten some where keep it some where.
if so then it should be something like this

```
$source=$_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'];
$filename=$_FILES[$fieldname]['name'];

    @move_uploaded_file($source, $uploadFilename)
        or error('receiving directory insuffiecient permission', $uploadForm);

    makeThumbnail($_FILES[$fieldname]['type'], $filename, $_FILES[$fieldname]['size'], $source, 100);
```

but i think its not that , your moved file name and thumbnail file name is same. so when thumbnail function is on bottom its give you thumbnail file only coz it over write original file moved by move function.

Comment: The variables didnt help. I tried doing the makeThumbnail BEFORE moving, but then it doesnt move it?